# In Behat How to Stage Link References in Table Nodes

Tags: testing

I have a Link field on an article that allows both internal paths and external URLs. How can I stage that type of content in the table node for the article?

(machine name: field_url)

I tried to use:

```
| field_url:title | field_url:uri |
| Test            | http://a.com  |
```

But the link Handler throws an error because when you use that format the array keys are 'title' and 'uri' instead of numbers based. (If I change LinkHandler to use the keys it actually works, but obviously breaks other things.)

As for the internal content, I've done entity reference before and they've worked on regular entity reference fields. But when I do something like:

```
Given "article" content:
| title                  | body       |
| Test Reference Article | Test body. |
And "event" content:
| field_url              |
| Test Reference Article |
```

The database gets populated with:
field_url_uri = e
field_url_title = T

Has anyone made this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article from [nuvole.org](http://nuvole.org/blog/2015/mar/24/pluggable-field-handling-system-behat-drupal-extension) helped me resolve the same issue you describe.  From the article:

> A Link field in Drupal offers quite a wide range of options, such as
>   an optional link title or internal/external URLs. We can use the
>   following notation to work with links in our test scenarios:
>
> ```
> When I am viewing a "post" content:
> | title       | Post title                                              |
> | field_link1 | http://nuvole.org                                       |
> | field_link2 | Link 1 - http://nuvole.org                              |
> | field_link3 | Link 1 - http://nuvole.org, Link 2 - http://example.com |
> ```
>
> As you can see we use always the same pattern: a
>   dash - to separate parts of the same field value and a comma , to
>   separate multiple field values.

The one note that I would add to the article is how to handle a link that has a URL, but not a title.  To handle that scenario, I used the following format:

```
When I am viewing a "post" content:
| link_with_text    | My link text - http://url.com |
| link_without_text | '' - https://google.com    |
```